# How to go for next View using collection View cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, delegates

I have a TableView and in that UITableViewCell I have a UICollectionView.
Now in my collectionView For each collectionViewCell there is a create cell and remove cell button option. So for create cell I have to go for CreateViewController and for delete button I have to delete respective collectionViewCell.

```
import UIKit

class TableCollectionCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    //collectionView cell
    collectionView!.register(UINib(nibName: "CreateGroupCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CreateGroupCell")
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

}
}

//Collection View
extension TableCollectionCell : UICollectionViewDataSource ,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
 {
    return 4
 }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CreateGroupCell", for: indexPath) as! CreateGroupCell

    cell.groupName.text = ""
    CreateCardView(viewCorner: cell.cardView)

    if(0 == indexPath.row)
    {
        //cell.btnDotted.tag = indexPath.row
        //cell.btnShare.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btnDotted.setImage(UIImage(named: "Info"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.btnShare.setImage(UIImage(named : "AddGroup"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    }

    else if(indexPath.row >= 1 && indexPath.row <= 3)
    {
        cell.btnDotted.isHidden = true
        cell.btnShare.isHidden = true
        cell.groupImage.image = UIImage(named: "group_dull_card.png")
    }

    else
    {

    }

    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if ( 0 == indexPath.row) {


    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: 200, height: 150)
}
}
```

Now in my didSelectRow method if (indexPath.row == 0) then I have to go for CreateViewController.

How can I do that? I am new in delegate also.

Answer (score 0):

didSelectRow method

```
     if (  indexPath.row == 0) 
        {
    self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CreateViewControllerid") as! CreateViewController.
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)

      }
```

Comment: Please read the question.
and see this is my tableViewCell class.
Thanks